Make HomePod as default audio output on start up for MacOS Sonoma
I have a HomePod setup using my iPad and now connected to my Mac Mini (runs Sonoma). However, when I shut down and start the Mac Mini later or wake up from sleep, it is disconnected and I have to connect it again.
In my previous MacBook Pro (Monterey), I had setup using this AppleScript on Mac.
delay 1
tell application "System Settings" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    get properties
    tell process "System Preferences"
        delay 1
        click menu item "Sound" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
        delay 1
        click radio button "Output" of tab group 1 of window "sound"
        set theRows to every row of table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window "sound"
        set theOutputs to {} as list
        repeat with aRow in theRows
            if (text field 1 of aRow exists) then
                if (value of text field 1 of aRow as text) is equal to "HomePod Stereo Pair" then
                    set selected of aRow to true
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Settings" to quit

However, it doesn't work on Sonoma, so looking to find a work around for it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
